# Pandas: Create Dataframe from list with repeating dates for each element

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I had a look on google and on here to try find the answer but couldn't seem to word it correctly to get help with this exact issue.

I want to create a Dataframe which has a column called 'Department' with values from a list and then for each value in that column I want the same datetime range.

The list is:

```
departments = ['Sales', 'Specialist', 'Purchase', 'HR']
```

and the daterange is (the df being a different dataframe I have with the original date range.):

```
pd.date_range(start=df.InvoiceDate.min(), end=df.InvoiceDate.max(), freq='1D')
```

So, I tried this but it gave me an error because of the shape, which I understand just not sure how to solve it.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(department,(pd.date_range(start=df.InvoiceDate.min(), end=df.InvoiceDate.max(), freq='1D')), columns=['Department',"InvoiceDate"])
```

The desired outcome is something like this:

```
          Department    InvoiceDate
    0        Sales      2019-03-25
    1        Sales      2019-03-26
    2        Sales      2019-03-27
    ...
    5     Specialist    2019-03-25
    6     Specialist    2019-03-26
    7     Specialist    2019-03-27
    ...
    8      Purchase     2019-03-25
    9      Purchase     2019-03-26
   10      Purchase     2019-03-27
    ...
   11         HR        2019-03-25
   12         HR        2019-03-26
   13         HR        2019-03-27
```

Thank you

EDIT: Error Code

```
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(workstream,(pd.date_range(start=df.InvoiceDate.min(), end=df.InvoiceDate.max(), freq='1D')), columns=['WorkStream',"InvoiceDate"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1678, in create_block_manager_from_blocks
    make_block(values=blocks[0], placement=slice(0, len(axes[0])))
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 3284, in make_block
    return klass(values, ndim=ndim, placement=placement)
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 2792, in __init__
    super().__init__(values, ndim=ndim, placement=placement)
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 126, in __init__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1, placement implies 2

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 464, in __init__
    mgr = init_ndarray(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 213, in init_ndarray
    return create_block_manager_from_blocks(block_values, [columns, index])
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1688, in create_block_manager_from_blocks
    construction_error(tot_items, blocks[0].shape[1:], axes, e)
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1718, in construction_error
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (8, 1), indices imply (533, 2)
```

Comment: What is the error pandas is logging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it, you can use below code:

> Declare list of departments and get list of dates from range(min and
> max)

```
departments = ['Sales', 'Specialist', 'Purchase', 'HR']

dates = pd.date_range(start=df.InvoiceDate.min(), end=df.InvoiceDate.max(), freq='1D').tolist()
```

> You want to have a cartesian product so use the below function

```
def cartesian_product(data):
    index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(data.values(), names=data.keys())
    return pd.DataFrame(index=index).reset_index()

cartesian_product({'departments': departments,
                   'date': a})
```

And here [link](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.05-hierarchical-indexing.html) you can read more about pandas and MultiIndex

Comment: Worked perfectly thank you! I cant say I fully understand what is happening in the function however? do you mind explaining it just so I can understand? @K.Oleksy

Comment: Sure! MultiIndex.from_product() creates a cartesian product for given objects, where the first parameter is data values and the second data keys. These functions create all possible combinations of elements from two or more iterables [see more](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html#pandas.MultiIndex.from_product). Of course, you can use other MultiIndex functions as: MultiIndex.from_arrays, MultiIndex.from_tuples or MultiIndex.from_frame. You can see more information about it in pandas documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling pd.DataFrame() in the wrong way. Also the 2 array provided as data are of different sizes. To solve you can do as follows:

```
 departments = ['Sales', 'Specialist', 'Purchase', 'HR']
 sizeDates = len(dates)
 sizeDep = len(departments)
 departments = departments * sizeDates
 dates = dates * sizeDep 
 dates = pd.date_range(start=df.InvoiceDate.min(), end=df.InvoiceDate.max(), freq='1D').tolist()
 departments = departments * len(dates)
 data = {'departments': departments,'date': dates}

 df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```